# Interfacing external high speed ADC techniques

Tags: adc, solar-cell, current-measurement, voltage-measurement, flyback

I am designing a power converter for solar micro-inverter based on fly-back topology (step-up).

I have to extract maximum power from the solar panel and for this I analyze voltage and current change with respect to my switching characteristics.

I measure voltage during OFF-time of my PWM and measure current (both high side and low side) during ON-time of my PWM. Currently I am using the on-chip ADC in my Infineon XMC4500 controller (12 bit, 1 Megasample/s) which is hardware synchronized with the PWM.

I wish to use external ADC with high resolution (16 bit or more). I tried with ADS1115 but it appears to be too slow for precise time measurement (100 kHz I²C bottleneck - my assumption).

How I can interface external ADC with my controller?

Comment: I'm almost certain (that is, not really certain) that the 4 additional bits of ADC resolutions won't help you at all. **Why are you trying to do that?** Also, yes, I²C is not a suitable bus for synchronous sampling; you can't use that.

Comment: I plan to interface AD7793 module ultimately (or equivalent). I tried with ADS1115 as it was immediately available. I wish to increase my resolution because when I scale up my system to (10A from current 1.25A) the step in current measurement is huge.

Comment: This is an XY question. If you want to extract maximum power, then measure the power delivery of your flyback, tweak your switching parameters, and measure again. Measuring at the output of your converter usually means you only need to measure a single parameter, like current, at constant battery charging voltage, or current or voltage into a linear load, where power varies monotonically with both. It's only if you try to measure at the panel that it seems complicated, where voltage and current vary inversely as you vary the load.

Comment: with a 12 bit ADC, your step is 10 A / 4096 = 2.4 mA. I doubt that's "huge". And even if it is, why do you think that by reducing the step size, you gain anything?

Comment: 1 Msps is a high speed ADC? That's super slow. I think it's gotta be at least 100 Msps to be high speed, possibly more like 1 Gsps.

Comment: @alex.forencich, For my application 1Msps is high speed. Switching frequency for my circuit is 57kHz.

Comment: @MarcusMüller, my plan is to use 1milliohm 1W shunt resistor to measure current. Calculations : Voltage Drop=IR = 10 * 0.001 = 0.1V. I have a non-inverting amplifier with gain of 30 to get output between 0V to 3V for range 0A to 10A. What are your thoughts on my configuration?